# My bottom navbar isn't showing on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile

Today when coding I've been struggling with a big problem. And after hours of searching, I can't seem to find a solution.

I want to make a mobile-only navbar, but it doesn't show at all on mobile devices. When I debug using the console on opera on little device settings, I see it, but only on desktop.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="menu-on-mobile">
    <div class="menu-on-mobile-item purple active">
        <div class="menu-on-mobile-item__icon">
            <i data-feather="home"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-on-mobile-item__text">
                                    Home                    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-on-mobile-item inactive pink">
        <div class="menu-on-mobile-item__icon">
            <i data-feather="user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-on-mobile-item__text">
                                    Me                    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-on-mobile-item inactive ocher">
        <div class="menu-on-mobile-item__icon">
            <i data-feather="code"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-on-mobile-item__text">
                                    Projects                    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-on-mobile-item inactive cyan">
        <div class="menu-on-mobile-item__icon">
            <i data-feather="message-square"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-on-mobile-item__text">
                                    Contact                    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my SCSS :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    .main-navigation
    {
        display                    : none !important;
    }

    //vars$white     : #fff;
    $purple    : #5b37b7;
    $pink      : #c9379d;
    $ocher     : #e6a919;
    $cyan      : #1194aa;
    $transition: 1s;
    .menu-on-mobile
    {
        background : $white;
        width      : 100%;
        display    : flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding    : 15px 15px;
        position   : fixed;
        bottom     : 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index    : 99999;
        &-item
        {
            display      : flex;
            align-items  : center;
            cursor       : pointer;
            margin-right : 20px;
            padding      : 10px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            transition   : $transition;
            &:last-child
            {
                margin-right: 0px;
            }

            &.inactive
            {
                background-color: transparent !important;
                svg
                {
                    color: #000 !important;
                }

                .menu-on-mobile-item__text
                {
                    min-width: 0px;
                    opacity  : 0;
                    font-size: 0px;
                }
            }

            &.purple
            {
                background-color: lighten($purple, 40%);
                color           : $purple;
            }

            &.pink
            {
                background-color: lighten($pink, 40%);
                color           : $pink;
            }

            &.ocher
            {
                background-color: lighten($ocher, 40%);
                color           : $ocher;
            }

            &.cyan
            {
                background-color: lighten($cyan, 40%);
                color           : $cyan;
                transition      : 1s;
            }

            &__text
            {
                min-width  : 50px;
                text-align : center;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-size  : 15px;
                opacity    : 1;
                transition : opacity $transition;
            }

            &__icon
            {
                display   : inline-block;
                text-align: center;
                font-size : 0px;
                transition: 1s;
                svg
                {
                    height: 30px;
                    width : 30px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the situation on my personal website: https://www.valodes.fr

If I restate the situation:

I only want to show the "menu-on-mobile" class on mobile devices, but it doesn't show at all on mobile devices.

Thanks in advance for the help :D

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  Can you give some examples of mobile devices you've tested this on?  That will help narrow down whether this is a problem on all small screens, all mobile devices or just a particular browser/OS.

Comment: Hi and thanks ^^. I've tested it on Safari and chrome on iPhone 11. Also I tested on Android chrome

Comment: Is your bottom navbar this one? `.main-navigation { display                    : none !important; }`